WiFi settings vanished after update
I typically only use wired LAN (which works just fine), but today when I tried connecting to WiFi, I realized that the settings simply do not exist.
Here's the result of running sudo lshw -C network:
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:ae200000-ae2fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 01
       serial: 74:5d:22:e5:f8:76
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-42-generic duplex=full firmware=0.2-4 ip=172.16.70.143 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:165 memory:ae400000-ae41ffff

And here's the result of running sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status:
Status: install ok installed

What's caused the issue here and how can I fix it? Will upgrading to 24 fix this?
Thanks!
Edit: Just found out that USB wired LAN doesn't work too.
Edit #2: Here's the result of lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0dc6] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:50d1]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
2d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]


Please edit to add results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

Added it. What seems to be the issue here?

You need the 6.8 kernel
